# Scaling firebase firestore scheduled event

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pubsub event that runs every 4 hours. I want to save all user's teams after the scheduled event. I am batch writing, but batch writes have limit of 500 writes per commit. below is an example code similar to what I am trying to do.

Question: How to scale batch write automatically.

```
exports.updateNews = functions.pubsub
  .topic("my-scheduled-topic")
  .onPublish(message => {
    return axios
      .get(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=someKey&sources=espn-cric-info"
      )
      .then(result => {
        const batch = db.batch();
        result.data.articles.forEach(article => {
          const docRef = db.collection("news").doc();
          batch.set(docRef, article);
        });
        return batch.commit();
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it myself Need expert opinion:

I know my code from question doesnt look like the one in answer I simplified the problem before asking question.

```
\\\ reference the collection I wanted to save to or the place I wanna write
var userTeamsSave = db.collection("saveTeams");

\\\ api call
  db.collection("news")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {

     \\\ create Json array from query snapshot

      let users = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(user => {
        users.push({ id: user.id, data: user.data() });
      });

      return users;

    })
    .then(users => {

      var counter = 0;
      var commitCounter = 0;
      var batches = [];

      \\\ array of batches
      batches[commitCounter] = db.batch();
      users.forEach(user => {

      \\\ limit batch write in 1 commit upto 499
        if (counter <= 200) {

          var thisRef = userTeamsSave.doc(user.id);
          batches[commitCounter].set(thisRef, user.data);
          counter = counter + 1;

        } else {
        \\\\ Reset Counter
          counter = 0;
          thisRef = userTeamsSave.doc(user.id);
          batches[commitCounter].set(thisRef, user.data);
          commitCounter = commitCounter + 1;
          batches[commitCounter] = db.batch();

        }
      });

      \\\ return all batches
      return batches;
    })
    .then(fullBatch => {
      fullBatch.forEach(batch => {
        console.count("wrote batch");

       \\\ commit all batches
        return batch.commit();
      });
      return;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      return error;
    });
```

Comment: To answer to your request for review, IMHO I see at least the following points:for 1/ You need to return the call to db.collection("news").get() 2/ You don't need to do return users;}).then() because you are not returning a Promise here. 3/ The same for return batches; 4/ Instead of fullBatch.forEach(); you need to use Promise.all()

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the limit of 500 writes for your batch, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead, as follows. It will return a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises returned by the `add()` method calls have resolved.

```
exports.updateNews = functions.pubsub
  .topic("my-scheduled-topic")
  .onPublish(message => {
    return axios
      .get(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=someKey&sources=espn-cric-info"
      )
      .then(result => {
        const promises = [];
        result.data.articles.forEach(article => {
           promises.push(db.collection("news").add(article));
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
      })
      .then(results => {
        console.log(results);
        return null;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Ty again I was thinking about commenting on my question from yesterday. Can you tak a look at the answer I posted the code is working and making multiple batched writes I just dont want it to fail. Need advice if I can improve it.

Comment: I am not yet comfortable with Promises thats why I am trying to avoid them my Linter screams that I shouldnt nest promises.

Comment: @Abdul-RafayShaikh Actually you cannot avoid promises if you work with Firebase asynchronous tasks! :-) I understand it can be a bit "scary" at first, but Promises are not that complicated if you spend time studying them! :-)

Comment: PS: I've added some comments to the proposed answer. I think you should try the proposed above answer.